# Transport Giant Gold flashing graphics

Tags: technical-issues, transport-giant-gold

Some time ago I tried to play an old game on my pc. The game is called Transport Giant Gold from back in 2004 made by JoWood.

When I tried running it, I had some very annoying problems with the graphics. Ever 10-40 seconds or so the game flashes to black. Not the whole screen, just parts of it. I'm guessing about 100 pixels high and over the whole width. It can also happen on any height and seems to be random.

I tried running the old game in compatibility mode, disabling visual themes, disabling desktop composition, but nothing really seemed to work. I also have the most recent graphic drivers.

A couple of days ago I found the game on Greenmangaming where I bought it. According to the website it would be a 2012 edition so I was expecting it would work. However, it has the same problems. Link to the game: http://www.greenmangaming.com/s/nl/en/pc/games/simulation/transport-giant-gold/

Some of my pc specs: http://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench2/1967872

How can I fix this flashing?

Comment: Whenever I have visual glitches or graphic-related issue, I assume it's a driver issue. Have you tried upgrading your drivers ? What kind of Graphic card do you have ? (did I miss iti n the benchmark ?)

Comment: My graphics card is the GT 630 2GB. And I have the most recent graphics drivers (for the Bf4 beta), but I also tried it about half a year ago and it was broken back then as well.